# Eclipse E4 RCP Logger - Get calling class or package

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have to use a separate class to for loggin instead of calling the LOGGER directly in every class i'd like to log.

I am using the following to do so:

```
    import org.eclipse.e4.core.services.log.Logger
     
class A {
    static Logger logger = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(org.eclipse.e4.core.services.log.Logger.class)
    
    public static void info(String message) {
        logger.info(message);
    }
}

class B {
    A.info("Foobar");
}
```

Now when I call the Info() method it writes the following in the .log file:
"[...] org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench [...] !MESSAGE Foobar"

Question: How can I log the class from which the Logger was called without implementing the logger in that specific class. I want it to log something like "!MESSAGE Class A Foobar". So i know which class or at least Package the log entry comes from.
Thank you!

Comment: Look at the standard Java `StackWalker` class (Java 9 onwards)

Comment: Note: `PlatformUI` is not pure e4 - that is part of 3.x compatability mode.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for the Info. Is there a pure e4 alternative? I can barely find anything online regarding Logging when its not log4j or slf4j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Logger` class Javadoc says it is not intended for end-user use. `PlatformUI` is not for pure e4 (you can't use anything in `org.eclipse.ui.xxx` plug-ins).

Instead you can use the `ILog` interface returned by `Platform.getLog()`. The Java 9 and onwards `StackWalker` can be used to get the caller.

I use something like:

```java
public final class Log
{
  /** The stack walker to get the caller */
  private static final StackWalker Stack_Walker = StackWalker.getInstance(StackWalker.Option.RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE);


  public static void info(final String msg)
  {
    final var caller = Stack_Walker.getCallerClass();

    Platform.getLog(caller).info(msg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your input, Greg! Is ILog pure E4? For some reason I was given the condition to use e4 exclusively without rewriting too much of the current logging implementation.. So if I could argue that ILog is the perfect solution for this even though it is not pure e4 but the same for e3+e4 i dont think it would matter.  I will give your suggestion a go nonetheless! Really appreciate your support! I am fairly new to Java so im sorry if my questions are dumb.

Comment: This is all pure e4, I only write pure e4 code these days. `ILog` is `org.eclipse.core.runtime.ILog` which is absolutely core Eclipse.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but since I have no way of testing it myself right now (or at least no way I am aware of) I thought I might as well ask you again :-) 
The ILog implementation works wonderfully, but since the project is pretty massive and it is a mixture of eclipse e3 & e4. I was wondering if I could also use ILog for e3 packages and if so, can you still get the class name of the calling class somehow? Since Stackwalker is Java9 but the project also contains Java8 classes. Thank you again. @greg-449

Comment: This code can be called from any sort of plug-in. Modern versions of Eclipse require at least Java 11 to run so this code is fine for those - even if your code was compiled with Java 8.